# Read only those parameter that has some value in SpringMVC/Servlet

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets

In servlet/spring MVC is there any way to read only those parameter that has some value.

```
e.g p1=xyz&p2=&p3=abc
```

In this case I just want to get `p1` `p3` not `p2`. I have long list of parameters so using `if-else` will be a very lengthy idea.

Comment: In `spring-mvc` you should be mapping these with `@RequestParam`. Deciding what to do with the values is application-specific, so that's up to you to write. No framework will magically know what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hey", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void addEmployee1(@RequestParam Map<String, String> s) {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (String key : s.keySet()) {
            if (!s.get(key).isEmpty()) {
                params.put(key, s.get(key));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(params);
    }
```